# Joomla 3.6.2 - wbAMP Plugin not take author from k2 article

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, k2

i have plugin wbAMP for Accelerate Mobile Pages of Google. But i have a problem about this plugin. wbAMP is 1.4 version, and when i start this plugin and I check with google developer operation i see an error:

"Field author is missing."
"Field datePublished date is missing."

This problem is present only for pages that have articles in K2 . While the standard items of joomla do not have this problem. Why?

Plugin problem or mine?

P.S. All items in k2 have all dates and author.

Thanks

Comment: Please contact the developer of the plugin

Comment: I suggest updating to the latest version if you are not already on the latest version and if still no resolution, the best advice would be from the extension developer as @Lodder points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**K2 Support:** According to both the [Weeblr](https://weeblr.com/frequent-questions/wbamp#community) and [Joomla! SEO](https://joomlaseo.com/blog/google-amp-support-in-joomla) websites, wbAMP support for K2 is added in the "full" version. You will have an additional plugin called "K2 wbAMP support".

Purchasing the subscription version of wbAMP will, also, give you direct access to support from Weeblr. They will be much more capable of handling any future questions you have regarding their plugin.